# Login, Register and Password reset in same page

Tags: html, css

I put login, register and password reset in same page and use java script on make only one available at a time. Is it bad coding?

Comment: The question is off-topic as it asks for opinions rather than objective facts. The relative weight you apply to certain coding standards, and how risks are apportioned is entirely too subjective to be answered objectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to actually post some examples, screenshots in this case would probably help. Whether or not it is bad code, it never is in principal, but in practise only by actually looking at the code.

If you're just starting to code, don't worry about what is good/bad code yet, worry about getting it to work, and the process I've been through to achieve it always with best practises in mind.

Review, refactor, rinse and repeat :)

Comment: The JavaScript code looks like this ....

Comment: document.getElementById("show-register").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("login-form").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("register-form").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("password-form").style.display = "none";
   }

Comment: that is perfectly valid JavaScript, however just by looking at it, there's something you could optimize, look at `document.getElementById("login-form").style.display ` isn't that a bit repetitive? Couldn't you improve that? (i know the answer, just trying to get you to get it it first) ;)

Comment: var form = document.getElementById("login-form"); if(form.style.display === "none") { //codes} ..... will this do the work?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're saying, you are only rendering one of the three components at a time. If that is the case, then I don't think that is bad coding. That might be bad user interface, since the user can only see either Login, Register, or Password Reset. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessarily bad coding, and there's a lot of personal preference around stuff like this. I think the general school of thought is that one component or controller should handle only one responsibility, and your page seems to handle 3.

It might make sense to make a parent container element that holds any shared behavior, and then display, for example, a child element with a sign in form, along with a button or link to register account or reset password. Upon clicking one of those buttons, the current component will leave the DOM (the parent container component stays) and the new component will display.

That being said, again, these are code smells, and it's not necessarily bad, but if you add more behavior later on, having everything in one component may make your job in the future more difficult